# numpy.searchsorted for an array containing numpy.nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I would like:

```
index = numpy.searchsorted(array([  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,   4.,   5.]), 4.2, side='left')
```

to give me:

```
index = 4
```

This works up to the value `3.9`, but not after the `nan` in the array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The array you are sorting is not sorted, which it need to be for `searchsorted` to work properly. `np.nan` would appear last in the sorted array:

```
>>> np.sort([1., 2., 3., nan, 4., 5.])
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,  nan])
```

To fix this issue you can pass in a list of the sorted indexes of your array using the `sorter` keyword argument. You can use `np.argsort` to find this:

```
>>> arg_sorted = np.argsort([1., 2., 3., nan, 4., 5.])
>>> np.searchsorted([1., 2., 3., nan, 4., 5.], 4.2, side='right', sorter=arg_sorted)
4
```

**Edit**: As per Jaime's comment below, passing the `sorter` argument will mean the function returns the position in the sorted array (not in the unsorted one). Since `side='left'` specifies that the first suitable index should be returned, the correct index can be better identified with the following method using `np.searchsorted`:

```
>>> idx = np.searchsorted([1., 2., 3., nan, 4., 5.], 4.2, side='left')
>>> arg_sorted[idx]
4
```

Comment: When you use the `sorter` argument, it returns the position in the sorted array, not in the unsorted one. If you had used `side='left'`, as the OP did, you would have gotten `3` as a return, which is correct, but not what the OP wanted. In this case, where the only issue is getting rid of nans, to get the right index you would have to do `arg_sorted[idx]`, where `idx` is the return from your call to `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: Thanks for setting things straight, Jaime. I clearly wrote too much in haste and missed details! I've edited to incorporate your comment, and can edit further if my wording is still lacking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough Reputation to add a comment, so I'll add my two cents in an answer.

I had a similar challenge, and as I understand the question there may be an issue with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256256/1634516).

To illustrate my point, I expand the array in question with an additional element

```
a = np.array([1., 2., 3., np.nan, 4., 5., 6.])
```

and call the argsort algorithm as before

```
arg_sorted = np.argsort(a)
```

Furthermore, in addition to finding 4.2, I also consider 5.2. Then, the output of the suggested solution is

```
for x in [4.2, 5.2]:
    ind_tmp = np.searchsorted(a, x, side='left')
    ind = arg_sorted[ind_tmp]
    print('x={}, ind={}'.format(x, ind))

x=4.2, ind=4
x=5.2, ind=4
```

Where I believe the more correct answer is found using the `sorter` argument, like so

```
for x in [4.2, 5.2]:
    ind_tmp = np.searchsorted(a, x, side='left', sorter=arg_sorted)
    ind = arg_sorted[ind_tmp]
    print('x={}, ind={}'.format(x, ind))

x=4.2, ind=5
x=5.2, ind=6
```

In which case 5.2 is found at an index one above 4.2, contrary to the original answer, and more aligned with my understanding of a correct solution.